# How to protect Perl source code using encryption

Tags: perl, encryption, cgi

We have an old website written in Perl which contains sensitive passwords used for connecting to certain databases.

What is the best way to protect the Perl code? We have very minimal understanding of Perl and CGI, but we need a solution to this problem as it poses a security risk.

We'r looking for encryption/obfuscation solutions, we read about Filter::Crypto::Decrypt but have no idea how to apply it. We also stumbled on this site (http://enscryption.com/) but we'r pretty skeptical about it.

We'd appreciate some straightforward guidance on what to do, with steps! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Fundamentally, you can't usefully encrypt the source code. To execute the encrypted Perl code, it would first need to be decrypted. To be decrypted, the decryption key must be available.

Comment: Now, you could move the credentials to a separate file. But that doesn't actually help. The Perl code needs to be able to access that file and the credentials within.

Comment: Yes the passwords are actually in a separate file, but they can always be moved to the code file itself. If we can't ensure 100% safety, 50% is better than nothing. What CAN be done and how?

Comment: @ZiggY If the secrets are in their own file, like a config file, encrypt the file. Then have the Perl code decrypt it. Store the key in an environment variable so it never touches disk. It would clear things up if you could provide an example of how the code gets its secrets. And in computer security, 50% security is often worse than nothing; it gives you a false sense of security and can demotivate real fixes.

Comment: It looks something like this (edited):
$conffile = "/f1/f2/f3/dbInfo.conf";

($p1,$username,$password,$p2) = &db_getDelimitedValues("dbName");

$dbh=DBI->connect($p1,$username,$password,'###')

Comment: @ZiggY Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53719717/edit) with any updates to your question so others can have the complete picture.

Comment: @Ziggy: Firstly, as you can hopefully see, putting code in a comment is a terrible idea. Please edit your question to add this information. Secondly, while you're showing us code, the contents of the `db_getDelimitedValues()` subroutine would also be really useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can't protect the code. [As Ikegami said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719717/how-to-protect-perl-source-code-using-encryption#comment94292815_53719717), in order to run the code you need to decrypt the code.

But you can protect the sensitive information. The simplest thing to do is put it in environment variables and ensure those variables are set when the program runs.

For example, if you have...

```
my $dbpassword = "sekret";
```

You'd change this to...

```
my $dbpassword = $ENV{DBPASSWORD};
```

And ensure that the `DBPASSWORD` environment variable is set to `sekret` when the program runs. This both moves the secrets out of the source code, and makes the code more flexible. You can store the secrets in one place making them easier to manage. It ensures those secrets are never stored in the clear on disk.

Similarly, if your secrets are in a file you can encrypt that file. Then have the Perl code decrypt the file using a key stored in an environment variable. Again, secrets are never stored on disk in the clear. This is similar to [Rails Encrypted Credentials](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2).

How you securely store those secrets and set those environment variables depends on your server setup. Once the problem of storing secrets is moved out of the legacy Perl code you have many options.

Comment: Hi Schwern, yes i guess that's one way to go. But if someone gets a hold of the Perl file he can easily retrieve what's stored in the environment variables by running the code, right?

Comment: @ZiggY No. Environment variables only exist in memory. You'd set them probably when you start the web server. Then only the server and its child processes, which includes CGI programs, can access them.

Comment: Understood. It's hosted on a Linux server (which im also not very literate in). But from what im reading, to permanently set an environment variable you must store the value in a .bashrc file... which is basically running around in circles. We wouldn't be much better off than we are now.

Comment: @ZiggY: what exactly are you trying to protect yourself from? There are (at least) two different levels of security that seem to be getting confused here. There are things that might accidentally get exposed to end-users of your web site. Anything that is hard-coded in your programs (or in any other web-accessible file) is in this category. If an attacker can trick your web server into revealing the code then you're in trouble. Stuff that's in `.bashrc` is different. In order to see that someone would need to have full access to your server. And that's a whole different level of problems.

Comment: @DaveCross, in my case, i have a web application running on Perl CGI. How would i set a persistent environment variable accessible by the Perl code written above by @Schwern? From what i understand, the .bashrc file executes only for specific users or when an interactive shell is started.
Btw, please excuse my limited knowledge here, i barely know much about Linux (i'm Windows oriented).

Comment: @ZiggY: You would put it in the `.bashrc` file that belongs to the user that your web server runs as.

Comment: I'v added an environment variable in .bashrc called testVar, but when calling ENV{testVar} from the Perl code, it's returning nothing. I even tried a code to loop and print everything from %ENV, and it's not there. What am i missing?

Comment: Does your web server read the `.bashrc` of your user and execute it before running your Perl program? Most likely, it doesn't. So you will either need to write a shell script that reads the `.bashrc` and then runs your Perl program or read the `.bashrc` (or whatever other configuration file) from within Perl. This will not solve your problem of safe storage of secrets in either case...

Comment: @ZiggY This is beyond the detail level of StackOverflow, and it's a security matter. At your level of understanding you could put a lot of work in and not get any security benefit, or make things worse. I would advise you consider hiring someone to give you a hand.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Perl FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html):

> [**How can I hide the source for my Perl program?**](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-hide-the-source-for-my-Perl-program%3F)
>
> Delete it. :-) Seriously, there are a number of (mostly
>   unsatisfactory) solutions with varying levels of "security".
>
> First of all, however, you can't take away read permission, because
>   the source code has to be readable in order to be compiled and
>   interpreted. (That doesn't mean that a CGI script's source is readable
>   by people on the web, though--only by people with access to the
>   filesystem.) So you have to leave the permissions at the socially
>   friendly 0755 level.
>
> Some people regard this as a security problem. If your program does
>   insecure things and relies on people not knowing how to exploit those
>   insecurities, it is not secure. It is often possible for someone to
>   determine the insecure things and exploit them without viewing the
>   source. Security through obscurity, the name for hiding your bugs
>   instead of fixing them, is little security indeed.
>
> You can try using encryption via source filters (Starting from Perl
>   5.8 the Filter::Simple and Filter::Util::Call modules are included in the standard distribution), but any decent programmer will be able to
>   decrypt it. You can try using the byte code compiler and interpreter
>   described later in perlfaq3, but the curious might still be able to
>   de-compile it. You can try using the native-code compiler described
>   later, but crackers might be able to disassemble it. These pose
>   varying degrees of difficulty to people wanting to get at your code,
>   but none can definitively conceal it (true of every language, not just
>   Perl).
>
> It is very easy to recover the source of Perl programs. You simply
>   feed the program to the perl interpreter and use the modules in the
>   B:: hierarchy. The B::Deparse module should be able to defeat most
>   attempts to hide source. Again, this is not unique to Perl.
>
> If you're concerned about people profiting from your code, then the
>   bottom line is that nothing but a restrictive license will give you
>   legal security. License your software and pepper it with threatening
>   statements like "This is unpublished proprietary software of XYZ Corp.
>   Your access to it does not give you permission to use it blah blah
>   blah." We are not lawyers, of course, so you should see a lawyer if
>   you want to be sure your license's wording will stand up in court.